# Dynamic Map Size in Nuxtjs (Vue2) + Vuetify + Leaflet (vue2-leaflet)

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet, nuxt.js

So I am building this App where I got a side menu on the left and a leaflet map (vue2-leaflet) to the right side. Got both of these components inside a v-layout row, nested in v-flex elements. 
The side menu got a google places search input which sets the center of the leaflet map to the selected location.

Problem -> when I don't specify a fixed width and height, the centered location is off.

My idea was to listen for the resize event on the map instance and then call invalidateSize method, but I can't really get this to work.

Any suggestions on this? 
Thanks!

Comment: what does it mean, 'the centered location is off' ?

Comment: i update the center property to any [lat, lng] property and it doesn't put the exact coordinates in the center, the center is off by a litle. But if I put a fixed size to the map container, it puts the correct location in the center

Comment: Can you check this website https://parc-epique.fr/ and let me know if this corresponds to what you are doing ? It also uses vuetify and leaflet. If so, you might want to check the code https://github.com/fchabouis/parc-epique. 

Can you also check if part of your map is hidden behind the side menu, which could explain why the center is shifted.

Comment: First of all: Thanks so much for responding, really appreciate you taking your time. Yeah thats my problem, map seems to take the full width of the view thanks!. I would really need to find a way to give the container a flexible width, because in the mobile version I want the sidemenu to be toggled visible/hidden. I'll try to come up with a way! Have a great day!

Comment: Ok so I got my parent container and my map inside with a width: 100% because I was thinking the map would just take up the full width of the parent container. But that is giving me my problem. So I need a way to work around this.

Comment: alright so i set the parent container to: position: realtive, and the child to position: aboslute and width: 100%. All good so far. Only problem now is that i want the child (leaflet map) to be fixed and not move on scroll. If i set the child container to position: fixed the centering is of again.